# Loop and HTML table in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a problem in my loop... I would like to display the `Belgique` value once. The variable is called `PAYS_LIB`.

Here is the [JSON](http://jsonblob.com/972233806983741440) file. The path => `REGROUPEMENT` > `ELEMENT` > `PAYS_LIB`.

[image]

Below, the `Belgique` value is created several times.
I want the `Belgique` value to be displayed once, please.

[image]

I don't know how to do this???

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of instrument.ELEMENT">
   <ng-container *ngIf="item.PAYS === 1 ">
      <tr style="background-color: #E7BCBC">
         <td colspan="7" style="text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold"> {{ item.PAYS_LIB }} </td>
         <td class="text-end item-price"> </td>
         <td class="text-end item-price"> </td>
         <td class="item-price"></td>
         <td class="item-price"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="text-end"><a [routerLink]="[ '/portfolio/stocks_movement/' + item.SVM] ">{{ item.QUANTITY | cphFormatNum:'1.2-2' }}</a></td>
         <td><a [routerLink]="[ '/markets/details/' + item.SVM] "> {{ item.LABEL }}</a></td>
         <td>{{ item.CURRENCYVALO }}</td>
         ...
      </tr>
   </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NgForOF provides several exported values, like `first`, that can be aliased to local variables, and used in the template.  `first` is a boolean that is true when the item is the first of the iterable.

Add `first as isFirst` to your `*ngFor`, and an `*ngIf="isFirst"` on your `Belgique` row. That should do it.

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of instrument.ELEMENT; first as isFirst">
...
<tr *ngIf="isFirst" style="background-color: #E7BCBC">
...
```

Check out all the exported values you can use with `*ngFor` [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables)